# parsing @include in yacc/bison

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

I have two config files `test1.conf` and `test2.conf`

The configuration options in both the config files are similar.For e.g.

```
[section1]
attr1=value1
attr2=value2
attr3=value3
[section2]
attr4=value4
attr5=value5
```

I need to let the user include one config file from another using `@include` or `#include` .How can I write a rule for this in yacc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31839746/loading-external-files-flex-bison-yyin

Comment: You don't want to handle this in yacc. You want to handle it in your lexer. File inclusion is a lexical thing, not syntactical.