# How to write parser which handles import statements?

Tags: parsing, yacc

I'm using lex & yacc to write a VHDL parser. VHDL has some languages features which make it context sensitive in a manner similar to C. For example, typedef-like constructs which impact whether the parser should tokenize something as an IDENTIFIER vs. TYPEDEF_NAME.

The difficulty comes in when you need to build a symbol table based on another file which is referenced by "use" statements (similar to "import" in Java or Python).

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

-- code which uses something defined in ieee.std_logic_1164 package
```

In C, this is fairly straight-forward because the preprocessor has already combined all of the header files into a single translation unit which can be scanned from top to bottom. But 'use' statements in VHDL are not preprocessor commands.

So, somehow, as I'm parsing the file, I have to recognize when I see a use statement and then go off and parse the relevant file, and then continue parsing the original file with that symbol table.

Is there an elegant way to do this with lex/yacc? I know there is yyrestart but I'm not sure if that's going down the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `flex`, then it is pretty easy.

The basic mechanism (including two functioning code samples) is described in the ["Multiple Input Buffers" chapter](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html) of the flex manual. You can also take a glance at [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31841036/1566221).

The parser (yacc/bison) reduction which recognizes the `use` construction can include the code which calls `yy_push_buffer`. In the example code, the end of the included file is recognized by the scanner (lex/flex), which simply pops the buffer stack.

Depending on the formal rules of file inclusion, you might want the parser to know that the included file has finished, in order to avoid having syntactic constructs which start in the included file and continue in the includer. (C allows this, even though it is almost always an error; I don't know anything about VHDL, but there are definitely languages which do not allow it.) One possibility is to recursively call the parser in order to parse the included file, which will require a re-entrant ("pure") parser. In that case, the scanner should return an end-of-included-file token when it hits the end of the included file, because your included file grammar production will need to be terminated with such a token.

You may need to worry about the possibility that the parser has already requested the next input token. Most LALR(1) grammars do not depend on the lookahead token for semi-colon terminated statements, and bison usually doesn't request a lookahead token in a context in which it doesn't need it. But that behaviour is not guaranteed by all Posix-compatible yacc implementations and you might be using one which doesn't.

In that case, you would have to preserve the lookahead token so that you can reread it after the included file has been parsed. That would most conveniently be done by stashing the lookahead token somewhere the scanner can see it, and having the scanner return that token (if set) when it sees the end of the included file. In a bison action, you can find the [lookahead token](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Lookahead.html) in `yychar` and its semantic value and location (if locations are enabled) are in `yylval` and `yylloc`. If bison has not read the lookahead token, the value of `yychar` will be `YYEMPTY`, and the simplest possible bison implementation would `assert(yychar == YYEMPTY)` when it is about to push the input buffer. If the assert fails, you'll need to implement a more sophisticated strategy.